# return reference of an object from an iterator

Tags: c++, reference, vector, null, iterator

I want to return a reference of an object from a vector, and the object is in an iterator object. How can I do that?

I tried the following:

```
Customer& CustomerDB::getCustomerById (const string& id) {
    vector<Customer>::iterator i;
    for (i = customerList.begin(); i != customerList.end() && !(i->getId() == id); ++i);

    if (i != customerList.end())
        return *i; // is this correct?
    else
        return 0; // getting error here, cant return 0 as reference they say
}
```

In the code, customerList is a vector of customers, and the function getId returns the id of the customer.

Is the `*i` correct? And how can I return 0 or null as a reference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`return *i;` is correct, however you can't return 0, or any other such value. Consider throwing an exception if the Customer is not found in the vector.

Also be careful when returning references to elements in vector. Inserting new elements in vector can invalidate your reference if vector needs to re-allocate its memory and move the contents.

Comment: Alternatively, he could return  a pointer.  Somthing along the lines of `return i != customerList.end() ? &*i : NULL;`.

Comment: It is just about possible to create a null reference with some iffy casting, but a *really* bad idea, and most likely UB in just about every possible circumstance.

Comment: Yeah, it depends a lot on the expected use of the function. If the initial expectation when calling the function is that the customer should exist, then throwing an exception makes sense. If its purpose is more of a to ask "does the customer exist, and if it does, return the customer", then returning a nullable type makes more sense.

Comment: @reko_t assuming the warning u told me was true, that the vector reallocated its contents when adding, how can I fix this problem if it happens?

Comment: If you know the maximum number of elements your vector will contain, you can reserve the capacity beforehand using the `reserve()` function of the vector. Then as long as the size of the vector will not exceed the capacity, the elements will not be moved when inserting new elements. If you don't know the capacity beforehand, consider using another kind of container. For example `std::deque` behaves similarly to vector, but will not re-allocate all of its memory when it needs to resize; it'll simply allocate a new block for the new elements (hence the memory is partially segmented).

Comment: Okay, I see
Thanks reko_t and everybody for the help :D

Comment: Also bear in mind that inserting new elements is not the only way to invalidate references to your vector, if you remove an element in middle of vector, it'll move the elements after that downwards, hence invalidating references/iterators to them. If you ever do something like that, then using a container such as `std::list` might be more appropriate for you. And lastly one way to guarantee that your references/iterators won't be invalidated is simply not to hold the references in memory for long enough that new elements will be inserted.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "null" reference: if your method gets an id that's not in the vector, it will be unable to return any meaningful value. And as @reko_t points out, even a valid reference may become invalid when the vector reallocates its internals.

You should only use reference return types when you can always return a reference to an existing object that will stay valid for some time. In your case, neither is guaranteed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the issue of validity (which is valid regardless of whether the function returns a reference, a pointer or an iterator).