# Iterator: If '*' returns the reference of the element, why does delete *(myList.end()) gives SegFault

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

Sorry if this is too basic for you. However, I would like to know why deleting, from a std::list, the return of the method *'end()'* with the operator *'*'*, gives segmentation fault.

[**Note for the code bellow**: I came with this idea because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550011/return-reference-of-an-object-from-an-iterator)]

Please check my example, so you could understand easily what I mean.

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    std::list<int*> myList;
    int *ptr1 = new int(1) , *ptr2 = new int(2);


    myList.push_back( ptr1 );
    myList.push_back( ptr2 );

    delete myList.back(); // !!<< this one is ok

    //delete *(myList.end());  // !!<< but, this gives segmentation fault
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `end()` returns an iterator that is one past the end of a list. It is out of range so dereference it at your own risk.

Comment: When do you mean one past the end, is it because the list is implemented with sentinels?

Comment: Good question. Don't have a good answer. For all I know it just holds a `nullptr`. Here's a reliable documentation page on `end`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end . Consider using `back()` for what it looks like you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `std::list::end()` returns an iterator that points to **one past the last element**, dereferencing it invokes UB. And because that address isn't allocated with `new`, as well as that it's not `nullptr` (Actually it contains invalid data), `delete`-ing it is another UB.

```
delete *(myList.end())
//     ^ UB here
```

To access the first or the last element (not **one-past-the-last !!**), use `front()` or `back()`:

```
delete myList.front();
delete myList.back();
//     ^ No dereference here
```

Reference: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)